# Compare dates of two fields with specific parameters

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'd like to pull a list of applicants based on comparing two data fields. Below is the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT
acc.[PersonContactId] AS 'SubscriberKey',
acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c] AS 'LatestAppDate',
unsub.[EventDate] AS UnsubscribeDate

FROM
[Accounts_Salesforce] acc

INNER JOIN 
[_Unsubscribe] unsub ON acc.[PersonContactId] = unsub.[SubscriberKey] 

WHERE
acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) 
AND
unsub.[EventDate] (insert sql if the unsubscribe date is 34 days after application date)
```

What would be the additional sql I should that that would filter for those who had unsubscribed within 34 days of applying?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT
acc.[PersonContactId] AS 'SubscriberKey',
acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c] AS 'LatestAppDate',
unsub.[EventDate] AS UnsubscribeDate

FROM
[Accounts_Salesforce] acc

WHERE
acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()) 
AND
exists (

  select top 1 unsub.*
  from _Unsubscribe unsub 
  where unsub.[SubscriberKey]  = acc.[PersonContactId]
  and unsub.eventDate >= dateadd(day, -34, acc.[Most_Recent_Auto_Loan_Application__c])

)
```